# Find coordinates of intersection points between a density and a line in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Once I have computed the pdf of my data, I'd like to extract the x coordinates of the two intersection points between the blue kernel and the black line as below (of type y=a).

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(10)
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(color_codes=True)
mean, cov = [0, 2], [(1, .5), (.5, 1)]
x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, size=50).T
sns.kdeplot(x)
plt.axhline(y=0.15, color='black', linestyle='-')
sns.plt.show()
```

Ideally, I'd like a solution that wouldn't go though the plotting of a chart as I need to loop this for different values of y.

[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged `seaborn`? You are asking for solutions of a mathematical equation; this is not a plotting problem.

Comment: There is no kernel equation available. A solution that would read the coordinates 'graphically' directly from the plot would anyway be useful.
And extracting X,Ys from the kernel would require people to know attributes of seaborn.

Comment: hint: seaborn doesn't implement the KDE. It delegates that to statsmodels or scipy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need and *exact* solution, you'll probably need to drop out of the programming world and derive the closed-form solution.

If a good approximation is all you need, simply interpolate.  You have the x and y coordinates for the plot.  Use these values to bracket the two solutions, and interpolate between the adjacent points.  I expect that a linear interpolation at the intersections shown will get you at least three digits of accuracy.